# MIME Error when using Vue-Router and Express

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, express, vue-router

Everytime I want to access a specific route in Express I get the followwing error in my browser while also having a default and blank Vue HTML without content. Everything works in Vue debug mode but after building everything, only the Home page and the 404 page works.

`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

In Express I have the following code:

```
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);


this.app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/html`));
this.app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/html/index.html`));
```

In my router.ts in vue I have the following code:

```
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";

import Natives from '../views/Natives.vue';

const router = createRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: defineAsyncComponent(() => import('../views/Home.vue')),
      meta: {
        name: "Home",
      },
    },
    {
      path: "/gta",
      name: "GTA V",
      component: defineAsyncComponent(() =>  import("../views/GTA.vue")),
      meta: {
        name: "GTA"
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/gta/natives",
      name: "Natives",
      component: Natives,
      meta: {
        name: "GTANatives",
      },
    },
    {
      path: '/gta/natives/:hash',
      name: 'Native',
      component: defineAsyncComponent(() =>  import("../views/DetailedNative.vue")),
      meta: {
        name: "DetailedNative"
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
      name: "Page not found!",
      component: defineAsyncComponent(() =>  import("../views/NotFound.vue")),
      meta: {
        name: "NotFound",
      },
    },
  ],
  history: createWebHistory(),
});
```

I appreciate any help.

EDIT:
So I found out when this happens. So basically if there are more than two routes for example /gta/native or simply /a/b this error appears even if the page doesn't exist. But I still can't figure out how and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer somehow. Everything was caused because I had a "corrupted"  `vite.config.ts`. After removing `base: './'`, everything worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `mime` module does not have a type mapping for `vue` ext.
You can check from https://github.com/broofa/mime/tree/main/types

https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static
Since `express.static` middleware support `setHeaders` option, you can set the header by self.

```
const express = require('express')

const app = new express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {
    setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
        if (/\.vue/i.test(path))
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/javascript')
    }
}))
app.listen(55555, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    const http = require('http');
    http.get('http://127.0.0.1:55555/test.vue', res => console.log(res.headers['content-type']))
});
```

Test output

```bash
$ node app
application/javascript
```

Comment: I don't want to display vue files